# How to pass django model field to function and have variables returned to context for use in template

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have some values that I collected from users in a form, which are saved to the DB.  I want to take these values, perform an operation on them in function, and then return them so that I can use them in them alongside the other context.

Here is my model:

```
#models.py file
class MyModel(models.Model):
    varA = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    varB = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    varC = models.PositiveIntegerField()
```

And here is the outside function that I am using:

```
#makecalc.py
def MakeCalc(varA, varB, varC):
    #simplified from what I am actually doing
    varD = varA*varB**varC 
    varE = varA+varB+varC
    return varD, varE
```

And here is the views.py file:

```
#views.py file
from .makecalcs import MakeCalc
class MySummary(DetailView):
    model = MyModel

    def get_vars(self):
        varD, varE = MakeCalc(varA, varB, varC) #Am I passing this correctly?
        return varD, varE #How do I send these to context?
```

And finally the html:

```
<p> you input: {{ MyModel.varA }}</p>
<p> you input:{{ MyModel.varB }}</p>
<p> you input:{{ MyModel.varC }}</p>
<p> I output:{{ varD }}</p> #how do I call this?
<p> you input:{{ varE }}</p> #how do I call this?
```

So, my question is in the view, how do I add varD, varE to context so that I can use it alongside varA, varB, and varC from the model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the [get_context_data()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/#django.views.generic.detail.SingleObjectMixin.get_context_data) method to your view, like this:

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = {}
    context['your_custom_var'] = 'your_custom_value'
    return super(MySummary, self).get_context_data(**context)
```